# How to make a row conditionally draggable in aAG Grid (ag-grid)?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Using AG Grid with Angular and wondering how to make a row conditionally draggable. For example if we want to make only the selected grid rows draggable, how that should get implemented.

The StackBlitz sample is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-ofetf4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per documentation: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/row-dragging/#enabling-row-dragging

> The rowDragcallback function has the following interface:
>
> // function to enable/disable RowDrag function rowDragFunction(params:
> RowDragCallbackParams) => boolean;
>
> // interface for params interface RowDragCallbackParams {
> node: RowNode;
> data: any;
> column: Column;
> colDef: ColDef;
> context: any;
> api: GridApi;
> columnApi: ColumnApi; }

So you should supply a callback to `rowDrag`. To find out if a row has been selected you can call `node.isSelected()`:

```
rowDrag: params => params.node.isSelected(),
```

When a row is selected you need to refresh the rowDrag callback by calling `api.redrawRows` on the `selectionChanged` Event:

```
  onSelectionChanged(event) {
    this.gridApi.redrawRows();
  }
```

See this implemented here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-cmda8j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts